# android.test did not get installed. Reason: 'Aborted '

Tags: docker, calabash, calabash-android

I am running calabash android test on docker and whenever I run the test the error

```
com.beats.android.test did not get installed. Reason: 'Aborted '. Aborting! (RuntimeError)
 ./features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb:19:in `Before'
 Will not start test server because of previous failures.  (RuntimeError)
./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in `Before'
```

is getting. I have tried the below commands and even after getting the same error.

> calabash console

Here in this case I will have to use the virtual emulator and I am running the test on docker. All kind of helps are appreciated.

Comment: What line of code is raising the runtime error if you run it in debug?

Comment: @alannichols I guess it is from the line **./features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb:19:in `Before'** which I have already mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: What is on that line?  That file is yours so there could be anything in there.  It's much harder to guess at what the problem is when without knowing what code is being run.

Comment: That does not belong to my code. It is from the calabash package itself.  And it seems like failing while the installation is happening.

Comment: It is your code as it's in your project lol, but I guess you mean that you haven't changed it at all from the default?  What is on line 19?

Comment: Oh really.  The code in that line is **install_app(ENV['TEST_APP_PATH'])**

Comment: When you try to install the app in the console, does it work?  It sounds from your question like it doesn't.  If you run the console in debug, does it give you any more information when it starts or when you try to install? *DEBUG=1 calabash console your.apk*.  Also, just to check, are you sure that you have ENV['TEST_APP_PATH'] set on the machine that you are running on?

Comment: I have tried it. But the same error was raising.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112185/discussion-between-alannichols-and-muneer-muhammed).

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @alannichols It worked when I try to install the apk by using the command **adb -s emulator-5554 install apk-file**.

Comment: Did this question get answered along with the other one?

Comment: No. It simply worked and don't know how. But the same is not working on other containers. sounds weird.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if ENV['TEST_APP_PATH'] has been set.